# Node reading from a file and writing to another file simultaneously

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

Does fs module provides any functionality where for every Line we read we write it to another file?

Comment: `fs.copyFileSync(src, dest[, mode])`?
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_copyfilesync_src_dest_mode

Comment: if you want to copy line by line and do something in middle, you need to know 3 thing: `Writable stream`, `Readable stream` and `pipe`

Comment: are these async functions?

Comment: yes, they are need to listen, `stream.on('end', callback)`, `stream.on('data', callback)`